# Using switchmap for single http request with Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use switchmap for an http request like this:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: any;
  _subject = new Subject();
  test: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this._subject.next('http://api/test');
    this.test = this._subject.pipe(
      switchMap((param: string) => {
        console.log(param); // should be http://api/test
        return param;
      }
      )
    );
   console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

I wanted to see the result of param but I am getting nothing. What is wrong with my code?
Later I want to use the switchmap functionality over an method:

```
callData(url) {
    this._subject.next(url);
        this.test = this._subject.pipe(
          switchMap((param: string) => {
            console.log(param); // should be http://api/test
            return param;
          }
          )
        );
}
```

After each request it should cancel the previous request;

Comment: Nothing will ever happen if you don't subscribe to an observable (Subject is an observable). And if you subscribe to a Subject **after** you emit an event, your subscriber will never receive anything either.

Comment: even if I subscribe the test variable of observable within the ngOnInit I am getting nothing

Comment: You haven't read my prevous comment, apparently.

Comment: Ok understood. But why I am getting the value 'hello' not in one line?

Comment: Your code doesn't have 'hello' anywhere.

Comment: Ok sorry, I can be any text. In my chase 'http://api/test'. It is printing char by char

Comment: If some other code exhibits some other bhavior and you don‘t understand it, then ask another question. I can't guess what modifications you've made to your code.

Comment: I just add this.test.subscribe((data)=> { console.log(data); // here I am getting the value character by character});